# IOS consuming wsdl web service in xcode using wsdl2objC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, ios6, xcode4.5

I tried consuming a webservice using classes generated from wsdl2objC
 i have this error

```
Thread 1:EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0xc)
```

on the method

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

right on this line

```
else if (xmlStrEqual(bodyNode->ns->prefix, (const xmlChar *) "soap") &&  xmlStrEqual(bodyNode->name, (const xmlChar *) "Fault")) {
```

i am really out of ideas.. been struggling with this for a week now... 
Please someone HELP!!

Comment: Did you check the soap message you get?

Comment: i have used soapUI and SoapSOnar and everyting is well

Comment: find a solution to the problem? I have the same issue..